# How can I scroll back the output in FreeBSD's console without Scroll Lock?

Tags: freebsd, console

I've installed FreeBSD inside a VM on a laptop. As it turns out, the laptop keyboard has no <kbd>Scroll Lock</kbd> key, which is used for scrolling the screen back in FreeBSD's console. How can I scroll back the output without <kbd>Scroll Lock</kbd>?

Comment: The question itself contained the answer I was looking for.  My keyboard has Scroll Lock, but I didn't know I could use it!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As root, dump the keyboard map to a file

```
kbdcontrol -d > mykeys
```

Change the file so "Ctrl+NumLock" will set "Scroll Lock". Find line with scancode "base" 069, or where "nlock" fills the entire line. Edit column 3 from "nlock" to "slock". The line now looks like:

```
"069   nlock  nlock  slock  nlock  nlock  nlock  nlock  nlock   O"
```

As root, issue the command:

```
kbdcontrol -l mykeys
```

The solution was found [here](http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-questions/2007-September/158918.html).

Comment: For People using FreeBSD as a guest OS in a VirtualBox virtual machine on Mac OS X you can also remap Cntrl-Caps Lock. 058 clock clock slock clock clock clock clock clock O Typing Control-Caps Lock lets you scroll back on the console as far as the scrollback goes. Bliss!

Comment: since this is a top result, I'll add that to make this change permanent (after reboot) follow the steps above, and then `mv mykeys /usr/share/syscons/keymaps/mykeys.kbd` then edit your rc.conf file and add a line with `keymap="mykeys"`

Comment: This does not work through ssh. Any tip on how to make it work?

Comment: @Pablo Lalloni: these steps work for the syscons on the system you are connecting to with ssh. You need to perform the equivalent steps on the system you are connecting from.  I say "equivalent steps" because if you are using Windows, Mac or Linux to connect to the FreeBSD system, the steps will be different.

Answer (score 5):

Laptop keyboards usually have a <kbd>Fn</kbd> key so that keys on a normal PC keyboard can be replicated. You should find that some combination of <kbd>Fn</kbd> and another key (hint: look for the blue text on your keys) will perform <kbd>Scroll Lock</kbd>. For instance, on my cheap netbook, <kbd>Fn</kbd>-<kbd>F12</kbd> performs <kbd>Scroll Lock</kbd>.

Answer (score 2):

I use `tmux` for that, you can install it from ports under `/usr/ports/sysutils/tmux`. `Ctrl-b PgUp` and `Ctrl-b PgDn` allow to scroll the console output in `tmux`. BTW, `tmux` has other great features, basically it is an advanced `screen` replacement.

Comment: WIll it allow to scroll back the output which was before starting tmux? Actually, I want to see all the boot messages, i.e. the output till login.

Comment: No, it will not.

Comment: The boot message are stored in a file called dmesg.boot.  `less  /var/run/dmesg.boot` might help you.

Comment: @Hennes This file contains only part of the messages, up to mounting the root filesystem. I needed the rest.

Comment: That is probably because before it mounts the root filesystem it had no / and no /var. And thus nowhere to write the log file.  --- Does your VM allow you to set up a serial port? If it does then you could use a serial console?

Comment: @Hennes dmesg.boot does contain everything since the kernel was started. It does not contain the bootstrap loader messages or any BIOS messages that weren't cleared.